# Numbers format of parsed table with simple_html_dom

Tags: php, dom, html-table, numbers, format

I want to format the content of table cells I am parsing with simple_html_dom. The table exists of words, integers or numbers without dec-points and float values with 2 dec-points. I want them to look like this:

```
before -> after
"abc" --> "abc" (can stay as they are)
"17" --> "17" (can stay as they are)
"24.24" --> "24.2" (rounded)
"24.29" --> "24.3" (rounded)
```

I've used this code to format the float values, but integers are formatted to 17.1 in this example. I've tried with `!is_integer($td)`, but then nothing changes at all.

```
$table = $html->find('table', 2);
$rowData = array();

// Selected Columns
$columnNumbers = [ 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13];

// Loop
foreach($table->find('tr') as $row) {
    // initialize array to store the cell data from each row
    $flight = array();
    foreach($row->find('td') as $columnNumber => $cell) {
        // push the cell's text to the array
        if ( in_array( $columnNumber, $columnNumbers ) ) {
            $flight[] = $cell->plaintext;
        }
    }
    foreach($row->find('th') as $columnNumber => $cell) {
        // push the cell's text to the array
        if ( in_array( $columnNumber, $columnNumbers ) ) {
            $flight[] = $cell->plaintext;
        }
    }
    $rowData[] = $flight;
}

foreach ($rowData as $row => $tr) {
    echo '<tr>';
    foreach ($tr as $td)
        if (!is_numeric($td)) {
            echo "<td>$td</td>\n";
        } 
        else {
            echo "<td>".number_format(floatval ($td), 1)."</td>\n";
        }
    }
    echo '</tr>';
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so, problem is on line:

```
echo "<td>".number_format(floatval ($td), 1)."</td>\n";
```

`number_format( $value, $n );` sets $n decimal to any $value processed.
`round( $value, $n );` will round any $value to $n decimals only if it contains more than $n decimals.

additionally, in second `foreach` loop you have `($rowData as $row => $tr)` without ever using the `$row`.
manual says:

> form will additionally assign the current element's key to the $key
>   variable on each iteration

which means unnecessary process for each iteration.

Comment: Thanks. Got it to work with: `foreach ($rowData as $row => $tr) {
      echo '<tr>';
      foreach ($tr as $td)
   if (is_numeric($td)) 
              {echo "<td>".round ($td,1)."</td>";} 
           else 
              {echo "<td>$td</td>";}

      echo '</tr>';
  }
`